# SQL Server 2008 and Management Studio - Intellisense is Patchy

Tags: sql-server-2008, intellisense

I'm working off an SQL 2008 instance that sits on our intranet. All is fine except that sometimes intellisense is there and working and sometimes it isn't. Its a pretty fast network so I don't imagine its a case that the RDBMS is reactively switching intellisense off because of latency issues etc.

Is there some other mechanism that can be used to ensure that intellisense always works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should revive when you refresh it's cache. In the menu is Edit - Intellisense - Refresh Local Cache (ctrl+shift+r). Or you can use another auto complete client like [SQL Prompt](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/) or [SQL Complete](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/). First one has only paid version, while the second has also a free version.